# Example.com in django password reset

Tags: django, django-forms, reset, change-password

I have set up my django project to enable password reset but when the password reset mail is sent, i get the line https://example.com/accounts/reset/Mg/... . Exampple.com is not in any way related to my site. I have tried to remove it such that it reads my site url but to no avail

Comment: you need to provide way more detail than this to get a reasonable answer

Comment: Have you the sites app enabled? check the domain on the default site, enter in your django shell console and do `from django.contrib.sites.models import Site` and look at it domain name `Site.objects.get_current().domain`

Comment: @flow, just posted the solution for future references from the community, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, django contrib auth uses current site domain provided by Site model in django.contrib.sites.models.

To check which one do U have configured, enter into the shell with the desired settings and type:

```py
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
print(current_site.domain)
```

This will show what domain will be used to construct absolute links like in this case, to reset the password.

Comment: print(current_site.domain) produced proper domain name however href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}" still example.com

Comment: In your tamplates, to build a full url, you can use something like `{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}` it does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check admin. You can see site domain in 'Sites'. Default of the site domain is 'example.com', so if you change the site domain to your domain, you can resolve it.